# How can a program change a directory without using chdir()?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I can find a lot of documentation on using `chdir()` to change a directory in a program (a command shell, for instance). I was wondering if it is possible to somehow do the same thing without the use of `chdir()`. Yet, I can't find any documentation or examples of code where a person is changing directories without using `chdir()` to some capacity. Is this possible?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: What is the underlying issue you are trying to solve that makes you want/need to change directory without `chdir`?

Comment: `chdir()` is a system call, there's nothing more primitive than this.

Comment: Weeelll, there's `fchdir()` and you can call syscall yourself.

Comment: @kaylum A professor of mine was discussing an assignment about building a linux-like shell program where he wanted a certain command to change the directory we are in. The issue is he gave a specification that we cannot use chdir(). I didn't know this was even possible. It looks like I may have misunderstood his instructions somehow since it doesn't seem like that is actually doable.

Comment: @October171, ...I've had a similar university assignment, twenty-ish years ago, but there I was responsible for implementing a virtual filesystem layer myself instead of changing the real OS kernel's idea of the working directory. If you're implementing a VFS layer yourself it makes perfect sense. Implementing a shell for a "real" operating system that runs programs that aren't part of your artificial playground, not so much.

Comment: @Charles Duffy After messaging some classmates, it looks like that's what it is. We're building essentially a shell emulator. We can "navigate" to different directories and see/execute some files in said directories, but nothing is actually changing on the kernel side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, `chdir()` is a syscall. That means it's not something a program does in its own memory, but it's a request for the OS kernel to do something on the program's behalf.

Granted, it's one of two syscalls that can change directories -- the other one is `fchdir()`. Theoretically you could use the other one, though whether that's what your professor actually wants is very much open to interpretation.

---

In terms of why `chdir()` and `fchdir()` can't be reimplemented by an application but need to be leveraged: The current working directory is among the process state maintained by the kernel on a program's behalf; the program itself can't access kernel memory without asking the kernel to operate on its behalf.

Things are syscalls because they *need* to be syscalls -- if something *could* be done in-process, it *would* be done that way (crossing the boundary between userspace and kernelspace involves a context-switch penalty; it's not without performance impact). In this case, letting the kernel do accurate bookkeeping as to what a process's working directory is ensures that the working directory is maintained when a new executable is loaded (with `execve()`), and helps to ensure the integrity of the kernel's records (making sure a program can't pretend to have its current working directory be a directory it doesn't actually have access to).